# Spacebar doesn't fill in tags as you type in IE10

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, internet-explorer-10

Normally when I type in some tags for my question, hitting space will validate the tag I just typed and add it to the list.

In IE10, this no longer happens, and I have to press Tab, optionally navigating to the appropriate one if there are more than one, and hitting Enter on it.

Strange thing is I don't see any error messages coming up in the Console...

Comment: The site breaks in numerous little ways in IE10 for me while remaining at least *functional* in some way... this isn't the only issue.

Comment: what other issues @bolt ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: Fixed in the next build.

So we're using one of the 2.5 billion jQuery plugins that detect the cursor/selection position in a textbox. This plugin was written back when Internet Explorer still required hacks to get this information. The way this particular plugin goes about doing this is as follows: Say your textbox contains `abcde`, and you have selected `cd`:

```
ab[cd]e
```

IE versions before IE9 didn't give you the position of the selection. They however allowed you to a) get the *content* of the selection, and b) *manipulate* the selection, both via a `TextRange` object. So the plugin took the selection and shifted its end to end of the textbox:

```
ab[cde]                 ->          tail = "cde"
```

Then it took the original selection and shifted its start to the beginning of the textbox:

```
[abcd]e                 ->          head = "abcd"
```

The plugin also knows the full content of the textbox, `all = "abcde"`. With this information, you can get the start and end of the selection:

```
start = all.lastIndexOf(tail) // or just all.length if tail is empty
end = head.length
```

Bingo! This works in IE9, IE8, IE7, and probably all the way back to the hot days of Geocities.

So, what changed in IE10? For some reason, after the corresponding keyboard event, IE10 immediately updates the textbox `.value`, but sometimes waits for something like 200ms to update the corresponding `TextRange` data, sometimes ignores spaces, etc. Bottom line: `TextRange` suddenly is buggy. Well, horribly broken.

So in your particular case, when the textbox looked like this (`_` is a space, `|` is the cursor):

```
some-tag_|
```

we got the following values:

```
all =  "some-tag " // correct, including space
head = "some-tag"  // incorrect
tail = ""
```

and thus

```
start = all.length  = 9
end   = head.length = 8
```

– and `start != end` means there's not just a cursor, there's a selection!

And when there's text selected in the tag editor, we don't render tags as tags, but make the full thing editable*. That's why you didn't get the nicely rendered tags.

Fortunately, Internet Explorer since version 9 supports the standard `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties, so the above hack is no longer necessary. I've changed the plugin to use the (apparently not buggy) standard interface by default, which makes the tag editor work as expected again.

<sub>*This is because the tag editor only *simulates* the behavior of a normal textbox. Doing this correctly when there's a text selection is impossible if the browser doesn't support `selectionDirection`, which only recently appeared in some browsers. Thus when there's a selection, we switch to giving you an *actual* textbox.</sub>